# Область определения для generic'а

Tags: java, generics

Подскажите как можно задать область определения типа generic'a при создании объекта?То есть в угловых скобках я могу вписать на пример только Integer или String но не Character, Double и другие типы.

Comment: Вы можете ограничивать обобщенные типы только типом сверху `Foo<T extends Number>` или снизу `Foo<T super Long>`.

Answer (score 1):

Этого сделать нельзя. Вы можете использовать огрнаичения на иерархию, например `something<? extends Number>`, тогда передать внутрь можно будет все, что наследуется от Number.

Как обходной вариант, можно в конструктор запрашивать класс и уже его проверять:

```
class A<T extends Number> {
    public A(Class<T> actual) {
        if (actual != Double.class || actual != Integer.class) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sorry, only double and integers allowed");
        }
    }
}
```

Но так делать не стоит. Как минимум вам придется подумать о том, что плоьзователь может соврать и сделать так: `new A<Float>(Integer.class);`. Ну а вообще это как то глупо, запутанно, да и нарушает The Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: так `new A<Float>(Integer.class)` сделать нельзя, поскольку в переменную `T` будет подставлен `Float`

Comment: Точно, забыл же за параметр в  Class<T>, машинально его написал, спасибо за уточнение )